# Event.observe function - observe element by class instead of id

Tags: javascript, class, event-handling, prototypejs

There is prototype js function:

*Event.observe(element, eventName, handler)*

here the **element** means element's ID.

Is it possible to put here element's **class**?

I got this element from third party with class attribute only.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[**`$$`**](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar) can retrieve elements by css selector, including by class via the [period notation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#class-html) `.`:

```
$$('.myClass'); // array with all elements that have class "myClass"
```

To answer your question, `Event.observe` is the "static" version of `observe` (for all intents and purposes). As a convenience Prototype [automagically makes `.observe` available off of *all DOM elements*](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/methods/observe) (fetched with either `$` or `$$`):

Examples:

```
// get one item by id with $ and attach an event listener:
$('myId').observe(eventName, handler);

// get many items by class with $$ and attach an event listener:
$$('.myClass').each(function(element) {
  element.observe(eventName, handler);
});

// or shorter:
$$('.myClass').invoke('observe', eventName, handler);
```

Comment: The problem with only being able to observe events on individual elements (even with the `$$('...').each()` method above) is that all the elements need to exist already when you attach the event, so you aren't actually dynamically listening to events on that class.

Comment: What if there will be a new element which is dynamically created during runtime? Is this also observed?